# SOLR DIH Adding document with multiple queries on same MySql table

Tags: mysql, search, solr, lucene, dih

I am Kind of Noob in Solr, Iam stucked in a Situation where I want to Make a full import to a Same Document entity, using multiple queries  on SAME Table based on diffrent conditions using Solr DIH . So it can be achieved ?

**My Problem (What I want to Do) :**

Say for eg , I want to define my data import schema like this , to Index entity with the data from `TABLE A` , Multiple Times based on different conditions , is the below format possible?

```
   <entity name="ITEM" query="select * from TABLE A where condition 1  And Some different sets of rules">
       <field column="ID" name="id" />
       <field column="NAME" name="name" />
       <field column="MANU" name="manu" />
       <field column="WEIGHT" name="weight" />
       <field column="PRICE" name="price" />
       <field column="POPULARITY" name="popularity" />
       <field column="INSTOCK" name="inStock" />
       <field column="INCLUDES" name="includes" />
   </entity>

   <entity name="ITEM" query="select * from TABLE A where condition 2  And Some different sets of rules">
       <field column="ID" name="id" />
       <field column="NAME" name="name" />
       <field column="MANU" name="manu" />
       <field column="WEIGHT" name="weight" />
       <field column="PRICE" name="price" />
       <field column="POPULARITY" name="popularity" />
       <field column="INSTOCK" name="inStock" />
       <field column="INCLUDES" name="includes" />
   </entity>
```

**On more Question :** How to SET MYSql custom `variables` in SOLR Data Import config file?

eg,

`SET @USerID = 0;`

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Defining several entities with different queries that import into the same collections should work as you write. You probably want different name=""-s for them, though (if you have to ask "Does this work?", just try it). You can use a UNION to solve the first case if two different entities does not work for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @Mats for your quick reply , I guess union will do the job . Anyways how to define `SET @USerID = 0;` in DIH document ??